# Program closes when server closes, write() gives no errors

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, gcc

So I am having this strange problem that I cannot for the life of me figure out. I searched everywhere but I cannot seem to find a solution. Running this code (snippet of full code) on Code::Blocks will run it fully until termination. However, running this on Terminal (./Program_name) will cause it to exit after the server disconnects (see **comment on code).

Why is my program running differently on Code::Blocks than on Terminal?

```
int main()
{
    //Rest of my code goes here

    while(1)
    {
        camera.takePicture(imageData);
        if (write(serverConnection, std::to_string(imageData.size()).c_str(), 6) <= 0)
        {
            //**Program does not pass here when running on terminal
            std::cout << "Shutting down Rover program: Server Disconnected"<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        write(serverConnection, &imageData[0], imageData.size());
    }


    std::cout << "Exiting program"<<std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    t1.join();
    close(serverConnection);
    shutdown(serverConnection, 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If `write` returns `0` it's not an error condition. When write returns less than `0` it *is* an error, and you need to check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) what is wrong. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) or [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to get a nice string output of the error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It gives me `broken pipe` on code::blocks which is expected since the server disconnects. However, running it on Terminal does not return anything at all. After the connection closes on Terminal, nothing is returned from `errno` , It just exits. Do I need to somehow handle `broken pipe`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I found the problem. SIGPIPE was killing my program. Can you write a comment on the answer section so I can award you/ help other people who may have this problem? Please mention to include `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` to stop SIGPIPE from closing the program/ ignore `broken pipe`

Comment: A `SIGPIPE` is the usual way to get notified that the other end has closed the connection nicely when you use `write` (the other way to get notified about it is when `read` returns `0`). It is a common problem, and there are probably hundreds of duplicates about this on this site alone. All good network-programming books and tutorials also mention it.